# Explanation about dummy nodes and pointers in linked lists

Tags: python, pointers, linked-list

I have the following class for a list node:

```
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.val = x
        self.next = None
```

If I initialize the lists `l` and `r` as follows:

```
l = ListNode(1)
l.next = ListNode(4)
l.next.next = ListNode(5)

r = ListNode(1)
r.next = ListNode(3)
r.next.next = ListNode(4)

# l: 1->4->5
# r: 1->3->4
```

and the dummy/current nodes as

```
dummy = cur = ListNode(0)
# cur = 0
# dummy = 0
```

when I set

```
cur.next = l
# cur = 0->1->4->5
# dummy = 0->1->4->5
```

both lists put `l` in the second node position, but when I set

```
cur = cur.next
# cur = 1->4->5
# dummy = 0->1->4->5
```

only the `cur` list loses the first node. And then when I set

```
cur.next = r
# cur = 1->1->3->4
# dummy = 0->1->1->3->4
```

the `cur` list attaches the `r` list at the second position, but the `dummy` list attaches it at the third position. I would think `dummy` would look like `0->1->3->4`

I figure this is something I'm missing either about pointers in python or linked lists in general. Any explanation would be appreciated!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The crucial thing here is that when you set a Python variable to an object, it's a reference to that object, not a copy of that object.  So in this code here:

```
dummy = cur = ListNode(0)
# cur = 0
# dummy = 0
```

`dummy` and `cur` both point to the same object (i.e. the same single-element list).  When you append your other list to `cur`, you're simultaneously appending it to `dummy` because it's the same list.

Box-and-pointer diagram:

```
dummy
  |
  v
/---\
| 0 |
\---/
  ^
  |
 cur
```

---

When you do this:

```
cur = cur.next
# cur = 1->4->5
# dummy = 0->1->4->5
```

you're not creating a new list, you're just iterating your `cur` pointer down the existing list.  Both pointers are part of the same list, but `dummy` points to the first element and `cur` points to the second element.

Box-and-pointer diagram:

```
dummy
  |
  v
/---\    /---\    /---\    /---\
| 0 |--->| 1 |--->| 4 |--->| 5 |
\---/    \---/    \---/    \---/
           ^
           |
          cur
```

---

Each time you call `ListNode()` you're creating a new node, so if you want to create two nodes with the same value, you need to call the initializer twice:

```
dummy = ListNode(0)
cur = ListNode(0)
# cur and dummy both have values of 0, but they're different list objects!
```

```
dummy
  |
  v
/---\
| 0 |
\---/


/---\
| 0 |
\---/
  ^
  |
 cur
```

---

Also: I'm not sure if this is what you were getting at when you mentioned "dummy nodes", but note that there is no particular need for a special "dummy node" in your list to signify the end of the list; `None` serves that purpose just fine (i.e. the end of the list is the one whose `next is None`).

Comment: This is helpful! But when we do ```cur.next=r```, why is r inserted at the third element of the list for  ```dummy```, but at the second element of the list for ```cur```?

Comment: Because it's still the same list but `cur` is pointing at one node ahead of `dummy`.  If these were arrays, it would be like `cur == dummy[1:]`.

Comment: General advice for learning about linked lists: draw lots of box-and-pointer diagrams.  :)  The crucial thing to understand from the Python side is that when you call your `ListNode` constructor you're making a new box, and when you assign a value to `next` you're drawing (or moving) a pointer.

Comment: Literally the the best explanation I have stumbled upon.
Great job @samwise

Comment: Everything I know about linked lists, I learned from SICP.  https://mitp-content-server.mit.edu/books/content/sectbyfn/books_pres_0/6515/sicp.zip/full-text/book/book-Z-H-22.html#%25_sec_3.3.1